# How to render a view in a nested route from an Ember select

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to accomplish a simple behavior:

Take an ember select view populated by its corresponding controller's model, bind an action that takes the id of that item and either renders or redirects to that view's outlet

I have ember select and bindings setup but how to actually render/translate that model into to the outlet has been evasive.

I have a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nidi/2/edit?html,js,output

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you had your transition defined incorrectly, it should have been

```
App.MoviesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    movieSelected: function(){
    var selectedMovie = this.get('selectedMovie');
    this.transitionToRoute('movie',selectedMovie);
    }.observes('selectedMovie')
});
```

Updated link http://jsbin.com/moki/1/edit?html,js,output

Actually, you just forgot to pass model in you transitionTo call, here is your updated link instead http://jsbin.com/nidi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Perfect and concise solution to the problem, I'd give an up vote, but I don't yet have the reputation to. Thank you much!